# Wordpress woocommerce checkout in elementor popup wouldn't show up

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, woocommerce-checkout-fields

When I click the add to cart button, the product would be added to the cart, but when I click the checkout button, and a popup would come out containing the shortcode [woocommerce_checkout], the form wouldn't show up unless I refresh the page and then click the checkout button again.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

**NOTES:**
On the woocommerce->settings-> product the ajax setting is check.
So I wonder if I could refresh the ajax not including the whole page once I click on the button so u could fetch the new data that was sent using the add to cart button.

WordPress Version - 5.8
Woocommerce Version -  5.6.0

Comment: To be able to help you, you'd have to provide a lot more information in the question. What version of Wordpress/woocommerce are you using? Do you have a snippet of the code you're working on?

Comment: Hello, I've updated the post and added the Wordpress and woocommerce version, and apparently, I don't have snippets because the website has a builder, but on the woocommerce -> product the ajax setting is currently checked.